# Android check permission for LocationManager

Tags: android, locationmanager

I'm trying to get the GPS coordinates to display when I click a button in my activity layout. The following is the method that gets called when I click the button:

```
public void getLocation(View view) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gps_coord_view);
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    tv.setText("Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude() + "\nLongitude: " + loc.getLongitude());
}
```

I'm getting an error that says

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user. Code should explicitly check to see if permission is available.

I have already granted these permissions in my `AndroidManifest`. The error is taken care of and the app compiles when I add the following before calling `lm.getLastKnownLocation`:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return;
}
```

However, the app crashes when I press the button that calls getLocation when it's clicked. What is going on? Is there  better/simpler way to grab the GPS coordinates of the device?

Comment: Probably you could attach an exception log.

Comment: Use ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,permission) and make sure you have mentioned appropriate permissions in manifest

Answer (score 159):

With Android API level (23), we are required to check for permissions. 
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

I had your same problem, but the following worked for me and I am able to retrieve Location data successfully:

(1) Ensure you have your permissions listed in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

(2) Ensure you request permissions from the user:

```
if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  },
                                                LocationService.MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION );
        }
```

(3) Ensure you use ContextCompat as this has compatibility with older API levels.

(4) In your location service, or class that initializes your LocationManager and gets the last known location, we need to check the permissions:

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
             ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
             ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return  ;
        }
```

(5) This approach only worked for me after I included @TargetApi(23) at the top of my initLocationService method.

(6) I also added this to my gradle build:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

Here is my LocationService for reference:

```
public class LocationService implements LocationListener  {

    //The minimum distance to change updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10 meters

    //The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0;//1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    private final static boolean forceNetwork = false;

    private static LocationService instance = null;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    public Location location;
    public double longitude;
    public double latitude; 


    /**
     * Singleton implementation
     * @return
     */
    public static LocationService getLocationManager(Context context)     {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new LocationService(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Local constructor
     */
    private LocationService( Context context )     {

        initLocationService(context); 
        LogService.log("LocationService created");
    }



    /**
     * Sets up location service after permissions is granted
     */
    @TargetApi(23)
    private void initLocationService(Context context) {


        if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
             ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
             ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return  ;
        }

        try   {
            this.longitude = 0.0;
            this.latitude = 0.0;
            this.locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Get GPS and network status
            this.isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            this.isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (forceNetwork) isGPSEnabled = false;

            if (!isNetworkEnabled && !isGPSEnabled)    {
                // cannot get location
                this.locationServiceAvailable = false;
            }
            //else
            {
                this.locationServiceAvailable = true;

                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    if (locationManager != null)   {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        updateCoordinates();
                    }
                }//end if

                if (isGPSEnabled)  {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if (locationManager != null)  {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        updateCoordinates();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)  {
            LogService.log( "Error creating location service: " + ex.getMessage() );

        }
    }       


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)     {
        // do stuff here with location object 
    }
}
```

I tested with an Android Lollipop device so far only. 
Hope this works for you.

Comment: I like your solution, but you should check if locationManager is null before using it, not later.

Comment: I get  "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'double android.location.Location.mLatitude' on a null object reference"  if I don't check for nulls at the time

Comment: I mean you should check "if (locationManager != null)" right after "if (isNetworkEnabled)" and right after "if (isGPSEnabled)  {" although it isn't really necessary: it cannot be null at that line because you have used it previously in line "this.isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);" and its value won't change to null in your code.

Comment: LocationService.MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION  this line not work version 23

Comment: the LocationService.MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION is not working to me as well.

Comment: @delive, LocationService.MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION -> you have to defined this int code in your own activity (which implemented ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback) class, for details please check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions).

Comment: When using ContextCompat you shouldn't be checking the Android version anymore, according to the Android documentation.  "This lesson describes how to use the Android Support Library to check for, and request, permissions. The Android framework provides similar methods as of Android 6.0 (API level 23). However, using the support library is simpler, since your app doesn't need to check which version of Android it's running on before calling the methods."  https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-check

Comment: COARSE not COURSE

Comment: @GökcanD It just updates the local instance variables, latitude and longitude from the last known location.

Comment: @keshav.bahadoor Huh, I get it.. However, this code doesn't provide correct lat and long for API > 23. It only returns 0 and 0 .

Comment: You only need to add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission if you plan to use GPS. You don't need to add ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission as well. Summary from google docs: Network location = ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission. GPS location = ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. When using GPS, FINE location is the only one needed (even if you use network as well). If you only use network, then COARSE location is fine on its own. ref -> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies

Answer (score 48):

## SIMPLE SOLUTION

I wanted to support apps pre api 23 and instead of using `checkSelfPermission` I used a try / catch

```
try {
   location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
   dialogGPS(this.getContext()); // lets the user know there is a problem with the gps
}
```

Answer (score 39):

The last part of the error message you quoted states:
`...with ("checkPermission") or explicitly handle a potential "SecurityException"`

A much quicker/simpler way of checking if you have permissions is to surround your code with `try { ... } catch (SecurityException e) { [insert error handling code here] }`. If you have permissions, the 'try' part will execute, if you don't, the 'catch' part will.

Comment: Useful if you don't have an Activity or Context object you can check permissions for.

Answer (score 9):

Use my custome class to check or request permisson

```
public class Permissons {

        //Request Permisson
        public static void Request_STORAGE(Activity act,int code)
        {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(act, new
                    String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},code);
        }
        public static void Request_CAMERA(Activity act,int code)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(act, new
                    String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},code);
        }
        public static void Request_FINE_LOCATION(Activity act,int code)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(act, new
                    String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},code);
        }
        public static void Request_READ_SMS(Activity act,int code)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(act, new
                    String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},code);
        }
        public static void Request_READ_CONTACTS(Activity act,int code)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(act, new
                    String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},code);
        }
        public static void Request_READ_CALENDAR(Activity act,int code)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(act, new
                    String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR},code);
        }
        public static void Request_RECORD_AUDIO(Activity act,int code)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(act, new
                    String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},code);
        }

        //Check Permisson
        public static boolean Check_STORAGE(Activity act)
        {
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
        public static boolean Check_CAMERA(Activity act)
        {
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
            return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
        public static boolean Check_FINE_LOCATION(Activity act)
        {
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
        public static boolean Check_READ_SMS(Activity act)
        {
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
            return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
        public static boolean Check_READ_CONTACTS(Activity act)
        {
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
            return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
        public static boolean Check_READ_CALENDAR(Activity act)
        {
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR);
            return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
        public static boolean Check_RECORD_AUDIO(Activity act)
        {
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(act, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
            return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
    }
```

> Example

```
if(!Permissons.Check_STORAGE(MainActivity.this))
{
   //if not permisson granted so request permisson with request code
   Permissons.Request_STORAGE(MainActivity.this,22);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i want to ask, what's the function of "int code"?

Comment: this code use to permisson result granted or decline on Activity result

Answer (score 4):

if you are working on dynamic permissions and any permission like ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION giving error **"cannot resolve method PERMISSION_NAME"** in this case write you code with permission name and then rebuild your project this will regenerate the manifest(Manifest.permission) file.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to check for permissions (rather than request for permissions), I wrote a simple extension like so:

```
fun BaseActivity.checkPermission(permissionName: String): Boolean {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            val granted =
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissionName)
            granted == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        } else {
            val granted =
                PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(this, permissionName)
            granted == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }
    }
```

Now, if I want to check for a permission I can simply pass in a permission like so:

```
checkPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
```