# Android Call Intent Permission

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to implement a call function in my application I have the following code:

```
Intent phoneCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
phoneCall.setData(Uri.parse("123456"));
startActivity(phoneCall);
```

I added in the manifest file the required permission, but it still gives me the following error:

```
Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException` less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection looks at Android API calls and ensures that the correct type of resource is passed to an int-parameter expecting resources of a given type; it checks that APIs which expect an RGB color integer are passed actual colors rather than color resources; it checks that APIs which require a certain permission have the permission declared in the manifest; it checks that parameters expected to fall within a given range actually do; it checks that results of certain method calls are looked at by the caller, and so on.
```

Do you know how I can fix that ://

Comment: From API 23 onward, it is required to check for permissions at runtime, since they can be revoked by the user: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: It's actually written on the error.. `code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with "checkPermission") or explicitly handle a potential "SecurityException"`

Comment: The error message tells you exactly how to fix the problem. Read it.

Comment: This is similar error but for location service but would give you an idea about what needs to be done. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491960/android-check-permission-for-locationmanager

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question contains the answer.

Comment: @AndrewBrooke thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your Target Sdk version is 23, you need to ask users permissions at run  time. Although you still need to include permissions in `Manifest.xml`.

Here are some awesome tutorials to get started

[Tutorial 1](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

[Tutorial 2](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-permissions-in-android-m--cms-24443)

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "your number"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Call Permission Granted..Please dial again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Call permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```