# new permission suddenly required

Tags: android, android-permissions

In my application I open the browser. The web view should make a call when corresponding button is pressed.

For this I have added a permission to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

I user a following code in my activity:

```
 protected class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This combination functioned well for 6 months. But today I have suddenly receives the error message:

```
Call requires permissions that may be rejected by user
```

I cannot undersatnd, what is actually required. I tryed to add an annotation `@RequiresPermission`, but it does not see `CALL_PHONE` from my manifest.

What should I add?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android check permission for LocationManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491960/android-check-permission-for-locationmanager)

Comment: did you updated compileSDKversion to 23?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Answer (score 2):

This is because your compileSdkVersion = 23.
For Marshmallow supported devices, you need to explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission).

So change the code as

```
 protected class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
            if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ) 
            {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
            else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```