# Error in mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing google maps api as a fragment in my project but I am getting error while adding setmylocationenabled(true). Please help me with this.
The error is:- "Call requires permission which may be rejected by the user.Code should explicitly check to see if permission is available(with 'checkPermission') or explicitly handle a potential 'Security Exception'

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import com.testgmaps.R;

public class GmapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gmaps, container,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LatLng marker = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker, 13));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Google Maps Test Marker").position(marker));

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491960/android-check-permission-for-locationmanager

Comment: Thanks David.I have tried that, but its not working. please let me know if you come up with another solution.