# How to check permission and request permission in (Easy coding & easy to understand)

Tags: android, android-permissions

I search for Run-Time-Permission in android and I find lots of links but I see there is complex code.

**Note:** I share my simple code here so it's helpful for a new developer or Fraser. Also, I didn't use any third party library here.

Comment: try this permission class to request and check permission https://stackoverflow.com/a/50760622/9821661

Comment: @milanpithadia I share my code below with easy coding and easy to understand for fresher.

Comment: In Kotlin or Java?

Comment: @SiddharthThakkar below my answer is working in java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android marshmallow request permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666071/android-marshmallow-request-permission)

Comment: @a_local_nobody I'm not looking for an answer I just share my simple code.

Comment: i understand, but this post already exists with a similar question and answers, or is yours different ?

Comment: I'm trying to make easy way by methods @a_local_nobody

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, Write permission in `Manifest` file(I take some bagic permissions):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Now I make two methods **`checkPermission()`** AND **`requestPermission()`** also `@Override` one method name is **`onRequestPermissionsResult()`** this is take care of result.

Now I'll show you how it looks like:

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
        int internetPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), INTERNET);
        int cameraPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CAMERA);
        int readStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int writeStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        return internetPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                cameraPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                readStoragePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                writeStoragePermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
```

You see in above code there is define INTERNET, CAMERA etc.. This is an import by clicking <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> And it is look like see below code:

```
import static android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
import static android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET;
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
import static android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
```

Now Please see below code of **`requestPermission()`** Method :

```
private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{INTERNET, CAMERA, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
```

Now the Last method is **`onRequestPermissionsResult()`**. In this method you can see either permission is GRANTED or DENY:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {

            case 1:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean internet = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean camera = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean readStorage = grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean writeStorage = grantResults[3] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (internet && camera && readStorage && writeStorage) {
                        init();
                       // Permission GRANTED (Here write your code what you want).
                    } else {
                        // Permission DENY (If user click on DENY then finish the activity);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Great you are done with checkPermission & requestPermission.

**NOTE:**

This above code is working for **`Activity`**. There is a minor change in the fragment.

**If I use this code in fragment then what should I change:**

> You want to just change in **`requestPermission()`** Method:

```
private void requestPermission() {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{INTERNET, CAMERA, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you think it's easy but it seems a bad way to me.
first `checkPermission` will be false even if only one permission not granted and you will don't know which one it is.
another thing is we should never ask permission when it's not needed, maybe user don't want to use the camera feature of app but want to use other. in that case this kind of approach will prevent user to use the app

Answer (score 0):

please try to  dexter  dependency

step:1

```
 dependencies{
   implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.0.2'
 }
```

step: 2

```
     Dexter.withActivity(this)
    .withPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
    @Override public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {/* 
    @Override public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {/* 
    @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest 
    permission, PermissionToken token) {/* ... */}
    }).check();
```

link :
       https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Comment: Dexter is out of maintenance now.